# PHP: Soap Client xmlattribute

Tags: php, soap-client, xml-attribute

I have try to use an php soap client.

But the SOAP XML needs to contain an XML attribute like "opCode=EQ" this example:

```
     <ws:Query>
        ....
        <com:Properties>
           <com:xx>yy</com:xx>
           <com:ab>cc</com:ab>
        </com:Properties>
        <com:QueryCondition>
           <com:CmpOp opCode="EQ">
              <com:Property>FolderName</com:Property>
              <com:Value>AB028</com:Value>
           </com:CmpOp>
        </com:QueryCondition>
     </ws:Query>
```

I try to read this by using this code:

```
$this->client = new SOAPClient(__DIR__ . '/WSDL.XML', array(
        'trace' => 1, 
        'exception' => 1
    ));

$this->client->query((object) array(
        // ..
        'Properties' => (object) array(
            'xx' => 'yy',
            'ab' => 'cc'
        ),
        'QueryCondition' => (object) array(
            'CmpOp' => (object) array(
                'opCode' => 'EQ',
                '_' => (object) array(
                    'Property' => 'FolderName',
                    'Value' => 'AB028',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

But this results in:

```
    <com:QueryCondition>
       <com:CmpOp>
          <com:Property>FolderName</com:Property>
          <com:Value>AB028</com:Value>
       </com:CmpOp>
       </com:_><com:opCode>EQ</com:opCode></com:_>
    </com:QueryCondition>
```

Can someone tell me the right syntax?

Comment: Why you want to query this array. You can directly call SOAP based api with CURL

Comment: Why should i build the xml by my self? It seams mutch cleaner and easyer for me to use the php soap handler. Otherwise have to build error handling (Exception) and all this stuff by my self.

Comment: If you have raw xml then you can directly post using curl. no need to use soap query function

Comment: Ok this would be a fallback solution, but i still prefer to use the SoapClient.

Answer (score 1):

All that stuff with underline i found in the internet dosent work.

The only working solution i found is:

```
$this->client->query((object) array(
        // ..
        'Properties' => (object) array(
            'xx' => 'yy',
            'ab' => 'cc'
        ),
        'QueryCondition' => (object) array(
            'CmpOp' => new SoapVar(
                        '<CmpOp opCode="EQ">' .
                            '<Property>FolderName</Property>' . 
                            '<Value>' . htmlspecialchars('AB028'). '</Value>' . 
                        '</CmpOp>',
                    XSD_ANYXML
                )
            ),
        ),
    ));
```